# Convert javascript array iteration result into a single line text string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for a way to check any text string (boolean) if a word is present using an array. Currently, I'm using include() method for each keyword i'm after, thus creating a lot of inefficiencies. I figured using a for loop will help streamline the process but I'm running into a snag, by where my return value is multi-line.

I can't seem to figure out why I can't convert the iteration result to a text string. I've tried .Replace(/\r?\n|\r/), toString() and join(), but have no luck.

```
function searchForKeywords() {
    let textString = 'This is a sample text string that contains a bunch of words, such as Semi and Metal. Happy searching!'
    let keywords = ['Clear', 'Metal', 'Silver', 'Semi']

    for (let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
        let a = (textString.includes(keywords[i]));
        let result = a.toString()
        console.log(result);
    }
}

searchForKeywords();
```

The result i'm getting from the above code is as follows: 

false

true

false

true

The desired result will be: false, true, false, true

Just to clarify, when I replace toString() with join() and .Replace(/\r?\n|\r/), I get

> TypeError: a.join is not a function ||  TypeError: a.join is not a function

I'm not sure why I get the error and as a noob and learning all this without someone to ask in real-time is quite frustrating. I'm sure a lot of people go through this... so please be gentle with me :-)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: sorry about that... updated it in my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the results of the check and join the values to a string with a spacer.

```js
function searchForKeywords() {
    let textString = 'This is a sample text string that contains a bunch of words, such as Semi and Metal. Happy searching!',
        keywords = ['Clear', 'Metal', 'Silver', 'Semi']

    return keywords
        .map(function (k) { return textString.includes(k); })
        .join(', ');
}

console.log(searchForKeywords());
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, but unfortunately i'm using Nashorn and it doesn't have arrow function capability so it doesn' work on my end :-(  This is the result i get: java.lang.AsertioError: Failed generating bytecode for <eval> :5.  Is there a way you can re-write the code using nashorn capable language? Again, I'm a noob at this and not really sure what the heck is going on. SMH. Thank you

Comment: I have to change .includes to .contains for it to work! Thank you. I'm gonna have to understand what you did there. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of outputting each iteration, push the values into a result array, and then at the end you can format that array with `join`:

```js
let textString = 'This is a sample text string that contains a bunch of words, such as Semi and Metal. Happy searching!'
let keywords = ['Clear', 'Metal', 'Silver', 'Semi']

let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    let a = textString.includes(keywords[i]);
    result.push(a)
}
console.log(result.join(", "));
```

Comment: What you provided also works! Thank you so much. Can I give a check mark to  your answer too?

Comment: That's too bad because you deserve it too! Thanks again.